# Multiple row equations in double column article

Tags: equations

this question is hard to show with working code example. I'll insert an image capture of my article. Consider an article written in double column. Now, assume that you are writing a set of aligned equations, each equation on a row and in flow with the text (i.e. cannot change the position of the equations in text). If the set of equations is too close to the bottom of any column, then the entire set of equations will get pushed to the next column, possibly creating an irritating empty space. I know that we could manually manipulate the set of equations and end the "align" and begins another "align" where appropriate. But can this be done automatically? That is can Latex decide where to split the equation between the two columns, such that all space is filled in neatly? See example below. Thanks.

[image: Example]

Comment: `\allowdisplaybreak` would allow column/page breaking in a display, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Possibly put `\raggedbottom` in your preamble

Comment: \allowdisplaybreak within \begingroup \endgroup did it. \raggedbottom did not work in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`\allowdisplaybreak` would allow column/page breaking in a display.